# INSERT into a new table using SELECT from another returns SyntaxException: "mismatched input 'SELECT'"

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql

So, I have a table called "tracks" (`audio_streaming` keyspace) that I try to change the primary key of. Since `DROP TABLE tracks PRIMARY KEY` didn't work, I try to clone the existing table `tracks` into `temp_tracks` then drop the original table and then create a new one with an auto-increment primary key and then copy the values from the temporary table into the new one. I tried to execute this code:

```
INSERT INTO temp_tracks (author, name, duration, explicit, quality, release_date)
SELECT author, name, duration, explicit, quality, release_date FROM tracks;
```

And it gave me this error:

```
SyntaxException: line 2:0 mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting K_VALUES (... explicit, quality, release_date)[SELECT]...)
```

And also is there any easier way of changing the primary key?

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

The exception above is triggered because CQL does not allow sub-queries.  Either you're running an `INSERT` or a `SELECT`, but you can't do both at the same time.  Nor can you run a `SELECT` as input for an `INSERT`.

So there are two options for doing this.

1. Use the cqlsh `COPY` command.  Basically, you [COPY a table TO](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-to) a .csv/.txt file.  Then, you reverse the process by running a [COPY FROM](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/tools/cqlsh.html#copy-from) the file to the new table.
2. Use the [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/install/dsbulkInstall.html) utility.  In this scenario, you'll run a `dsbulk unload` to a file, and then a `dsbulk load` to the new table.

Either one should work, although DSBulk does a better job of handling large amounts of data.  So if your row count is in the thousands, cqlsh COPY should be fine.  If it's a million rows or more, use DSBulk.

Answer (score 1):

The CQL grammar doesn't support SQL syntax that copies data from one table to another like:

```
INSERT INTO destination_tbl
SELECT * FROM source_table
...
```

Cassandra is designed for OLTP workloads where reads are optimised for single-partition retrieval.

In contrast, copying data from one table to another is closer to an analytics workload that requires a full table scan which doesn't scale. Imagine if you had billions and billions of records in a table that is distributed across hundreds of nodes -- the copy query will take forever and likely timeout. Cassandra simply isn't designed to handle that kind of operation.

The closest CQL syntax that exists is for creating materialized views which includes the `AS SELECT` clause:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name
AS SELECT ... FROM source_table
WHERE ...
```

This DDL statement creates a MV table which is populated by data from a base table. However, the data "copy" takes place asynchronously over a period of time depending on how much data exists in the base table. The copy is asynchronous because, again, it requires a full table scan which will affect the performance of the cluster if it was not throttled.

As a side note, materialized views are classified as experimental so I wouldn't recommend using it in production unless (1) you have a good [understanding of how it works](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/understandMV.html), and (2) [know its limitations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/knownLimitationsMV.html). I've explained it in a bit more detail in this post -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325482/.

Your options are:

- Write an application that reads each partition and save it in the new table.
- Use Spark to perform an ETL into the new table.
- Use [DataStax Bulk Loader (DSBulk)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html) to export the data out and bulk-load it to the new table.

If you decide to go down the DSBulk path, here are some resources that will help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [Introduction to DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/introducing-datastax-bulk-loader)
- Blog - [Examples for exporting tables](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-unloading)
- Docs - [Unloading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkUnload.html)
- Blog - [More examples for loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting) (for verifying exports/imports)